# MediaWiki like wiki, but with user management?

Tags: linux, web, wiki, documentation, mediawiki

I really like the syntax of MediaWiki, and that it doesn't use a rich editor, but I would very much like if it had user management.

As far as I can tell, the page is either locked or open for anyone to edit.

Does the exist a MediaWiki like wiki, but with user management that runs on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some control via configuration and special pages

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights

Also see some other links on the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki)

> DokuWiki is a standards compliant, simple to use Wiki, mainly aimed at creating documentation of any kind. It is targeted at developer teams, workgroups and small companies. It has a simple but powerful syntax which makes sure the datafiles remain readable outside the Wiki and eases the creation of structured texts. All data is stored in plain text files – no database is required.

It includes an ACL system